# me pueden explicar el error de estos JradioButton

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Hola soy bastante novata en java y estoy haciendo un programa donde se haga esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasa lo siguiente se debe aplicar un descuento cuando se selecciona cliente activo si se selecciona cliente nuevo no se hace el descuento.
en mi ventana esta este código:

```
  if (rbt_activo.isSelected()) {

                tipocliente.setCliente(true);

            }

            if (rbt_nuevo.isSelected()) {

                tipocliente.setCliente(false);
            }
```

Este es el código de la ventana para enviarlo a una clase padre  y de la clase padre lo envió a una clase hija porque estoy aplicando el polimorfismo.

**En la clase hija este es el código**

```
 rentaPagar = (int) (montoPrestamo * interes / (1 - 1 / (1 + interes) / meses));

        if (cliente == true) {

            if (descuentoMensual >= 1 && descuentoMensual <= 5) {

                return rentaPagar - (0.01 * rentaPagar);
                
            } else {
                
                return rentaPagar - (0.03 * rentaPagar);
                
            }

        }else{
            
            return rentaPagar;
        }
```

**Osea solo hago el descuento cuando es activo y sino se cumple se retorna el calculo sin el descuento para cliente nuevo, pero el calculo no se hace ya que no arroja bien nada, para cualquiera de los dos botones me retorna el calculo sin impuesto, no se que puedo hacer?**

Comment: Me gustaría ver el código completo, porque parece que te estas complicando; lo que debes hacer es trabajar la lógica en el ``ActionPerformed`` del botón y ahi validar cual de los 2 JRadioButton está seleccionado.

Comment: es que el problema es que son 4 ventanas y 4 clases entonces pasarte todo el codigo es complicado y es una tarea sobre polimorfismo, herencia etc

Comment: que consideras tu que deberia hacer entonces?

Comment: Tendrías que mostrarnos la declaración y asignación de la variable `cliente`.

Answer (score 0):

Al no tener mayor detalle del resto de tu código, responderé tu consulta principal

> se debe aplicar un descuento cuando se selecciona cliente activo si se selecciona cliente nuevo no se hace el descuento

Para ello la validación de los campos se debe realizar en el evento `ActionPerformed` del `JButton` ya que es esto el que realizará la lógica de los componentes que tienes en tu ventana.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:        
        double rentaPagar;
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
            //Aqui la lógica de lo que sucede con renta cuando CLIENTE ACTIVO está seleccionado            
        }
        else{
            //Aqui la lógica de lo que sucede con renta cuando CLIENTE nuevo está seleccionado
        }
    }
```

La idea es general y es valido si dentro de la lógica tienes que llamar a otras ventanas o métodos de otras clases o de la misma clase

Comment: es que el problema @Joshin es que en mi proyecto estoy aplicando el polimorfismo, la herencia, entonces eso que me mandas lo tengo echo hasta la clase hija osea tengo la ventana la clase padre y luego la clase hija de este calculo en especifico, entonces no tengo forma de aplicar esa logica de un if y el JradioButon en la clase hija, porque eso que me dices lo puedo hacer en la ventana pero oviamente debo hacer exactamente eso desde su clase hija entonces no tengo como hacer eso que comentas de esa forma **por esa razon desde la ventana estoy mandando un booleano de si es falso o verdadero**

Comment: Me gustaría ayudarte pero no llego a entenderte de todo, si puedes explicar un poco la lógica de lo que realizan ``tipocliente`` y ``cliente``, talvez la forma en como lo estás trabajando no es la mejor y se pueda mejorar. estaré desconectado unas 17 horas; espero que alguien pueda ayudarte antes de ese tiempo

Comment: como ves en la clase hija,  si el cliente es activo se le realiza dos descuento dependiendo del total de productos que compro por su condicion de cliente activo, y si el cliente es nuevo no se le realiza ningun descuento por ser un cliente nuevo, solo los clientes activos tienen el privilegio de resivir ese descuento

Comment: entonces si tu pones cliente activo se te hace un descuento dependiendo del total de productos que ingreses si eres un cliente normal no se te realiza ningun descuento entonces el calculo se hace normal sin ningun descuento